# Data from excel query is not in number format

Tags: excel, number-formatting, microsoft-query

I am querying using Excel 2013-DATA tab-From Other Sources-From Microsoft Query. Everything works I am getting what I need but the format of numbers is not in right format and I am doing everything to change it but I can't. I know escel quite well, so I tried everything that everybody would try first and the post. Nothing worked, I want my list to be live and I want to be able to work with numbers. Now I can't do even basic function like sum, min or max. But there is something weird happens when you edit. When you click on cell and I do not change anything and becomes number format. For example; B1, A3, B7, A11 are some examples. Please help me to make numbers coming from excel query to be in a number format. Let me know if my question is not clear. Please note that it is in table format. Thanks

[Please see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzdPO.jpg)

Comment: data is coming from text/csv?

Comment: As I mentioned, it is coming from microsoft-query in Excel and it is xlsx not csv/text.

Comment: Doesn't Microsoft Query have to connect to some data... stored in a file... which would be some file type by the nature that it exists.

Comment: Just curious, why you are using MsQuery to move data from one spreadsheet to another.

Comment: I am querying from database through microsoft sql query. I am building a model that needs to be live. I am not moving data from one spreadsheet to another, I am getting data from sql server and importing it into Excel. everything is fine, except the format of numbers. I have ways to do it but I want it to happen automatically with one shot. So when data comes from sql server, i want it to be in number format.

Comment: if anyone has any other idea how to get data from query into Excel, please let me know

Comment: hmm... one more thing, can you post your SQL query here?

Comment: why would you need SQL query? it has nothing to do with sql query, it is about number formatting in excel

Answer (score -1):

Rovshan,

In my experience the formatting when exporting from SQL to excel is not always convenient, even if you format the query results prior to "Close & Load" of the query it still converts it to Text or General in some cases.

What I recommend you try is run your query as normal, format your results in the manner in which you want them to appear normally, then under the "Data" tab select "Properties

Here you´re going to check the box that states
"Preserve column sort/filter/layout"

[image]

This should preserve your format for future query updates. Note that this is specific to this query within this workbook, it will not be the default for other queries.

Regards,